# Use only one type of unit on an axis in D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have an axis where I have values:

```
500000
600000
1000000
2000000
```

D3 by default formats first two as '500k', '600k', and last two as '1.0M', '2.0M'.

I need to use only one type of unit, like getting the max value and use it as a reference for all other ticks, like get 2000000, format it like '2.0M', then the rest will be '1.0M', '0.6M', '0.5M'.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: [`axis.tickFormat()`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Axes#tickFormat) with a suitable [`d3.format()`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Formatting#d3_format).

Answer (score 0):

You would need to define the desired prefix (e.g., M for millions) formatter:

```
var formatInteger = d3.format(".f"),
formatMillions = function (d) {
    return formatInteger(d / 1e6) + "M";
};
```

And pass it to .tickFormat

```
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(axisScale)
  .tickFormat(formatMillions);
```

Complete example is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/v9ch8w8a/).

Also, you can find more about [tickFormat](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Quantitative-Scales#linear_tickFormat) and [formatting](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Formatting).